# The developing XCover 3 phone is unsupported in Play Store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, adb, compatibility

I know there are similar questions but none of them helped me.
The phone is a *Samsung Galaxy XCover 3*.

I developed the app on an *Xcover 4*. I uploaded it to Play Store and it says, it doesn't support *XCover 3*. (The *XCover 4* is supported in Play Store.)

After that I tried to launch the app on the *XCover 3* from Android Studio and it worked. But Play Store says it's unsupported.

In the *device catalog* int the *google play developer console* the *XCover 3* is supported.

My APK is 48MB. ([This is it.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.feverkill.gatsj.balanceblockbattle))

I paste here the Manifest file and the build.gradle file from Android Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.feverkill.gatsj.balanceblockbattle">

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity android:name="com.feverkill.gatsj.balanceblockbattle.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.feverkill.gatsj.balanceblockbattle"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What can cause this problem?

<sub>(Yes, I contacted developer support but they couldn't help. They said: "we are not technically trained on app development questions, I am unable to confirm the specific reason on why it is not compatible".)</sub>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/62576). Direct support questions to that company via their web site instead. Guidelines for this site can be found in the [help].

Comment: I think this is a problem of parameters in an app build. There is nothing about customer service.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would either be the Open GL version requirement, or the minSdkVersion. What is the android version on the XCover3 where it won't install?

Google Play Console developer support are very good and can help with questions like this, and they have a lot of information about you and your app. I'd recommend contacting them through the help links in the Google Play Console.

Comment: The XC 3 runs 5.1.1, so API level 22. This is higher than the specified 19. The GL version should be compatible. The phone supports GL ES 3.0.

(I contacted them but they couldn't help. They said: "we are not technically trained on app development questions, I am unable to confirm the specific reason on why it is not compatible")

Comment: It is an Open GL issue. I just checked the phone and it is reporting Open GL2 (you might be able to see this as ro.opengles.version=131072. OpenGL ES 3.0 requires ro.opengles.version=196608)